# Error in bring up Turtlebot3

Tags: turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, i am very new to this. When I launched my turtlebot3, the lidar starts spinning and it seems to be working but get this message:

```
[ERROR] [1501190507.582025]: Error opening serial: [Errno 2] could not open port /dev/ttyACM0: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/dev/ttyACM0'
```

The thing is I previously connect the opencr board to with wrong wire and it caused a short, so the opencr board is likely to be damaged. Is this error message related to the short problem.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/267562/error-in-bring-up-turtlebot3/) by [rozoalex](https://answers.ros.org/users/31065/rozoalex/) on ROS Answers with karma: 113 on 2017-07-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you follow these instructions to setup the USB rules on your single board computer?

[6.4. USB Settings (Burger and Waffle)](http://turtlebot3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sbc_software.html#usb-settings-burger-and-waffle)

---

Originally posted by [Marq](https://answers.ros.org/users/26396/marq/) with karma: 61 on 2017-07-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bawboc](https://answers.ros.org/users/37923/bawboc/) on 2018-10-05**:
Dead link.